# nodejs server opens and closes quickly after react-native run-android

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have installed and built my first React Native app from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).
when I run `react-native run-android`, `nodes server` has been opened and closed quickly.

this is my projects info: [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfWhR.png)

the following image is when I have run `react-native run-android`.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwhcf.png)

the following image is when `nodejs server` has been closed.
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfQqc.png)

**what is the problem?**

Comment: their has been no problem with node server,their should be any other problem

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open Your Project Folder in IDE like Visual Studio Code etc

Click on node_modules folder

Click on metro-config folder

Click on src folder

Click on default folder

Open blacklist.js file and replace the following code

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

with

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
/website\/node_modules\/.*/,
/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
/.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Comment: Magically this fixed my issue.

Comment: love you man, works like a charm, may i know what's the issue ?

Comment: This does not work for me, and an explanation of why it works for you would be super helpful

Answer (score 1):

just simply open two terminal inside the project folder then first run on the 1st terminal ( npx react-native start) to run the server then open the other terminal and run ( npx react-native run-androi/run-ios) to run the application on your android/ios device

Answer (score -1):

Updating [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) to the latest version solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

I tried updating sharedBlacklist variable but still it doesn't always works.

What works for me is this. After running the command react-native run-android, nodejs server will appear. Wait for a while(probably a minute or so) IF the nodejs server is closed, kill this process by pressing Ctrl+C. After that, run react-native run-android again. This time the nodejs server will remain open.

You might need to repeat the process again if the nodejs server still closes. But from my experience the max I need to do is just twice. Good luck!